# Voting down and/or closing questions when being nice

Tags: discussion, deleting, vote-to-close, etiquette, down-votes

Following on from [Being nice when closing questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/96) and [Being nice when down voting](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353/96) .

While being nice is essential, so is:

- voting down bad questions;
- voting to close questions that don't belong here or are duplicates; and
- voting to delete questions that don't belong here.

What can we do to encourage more of this sort of thing?

*Related:*

- [What is community moderation, and what can I do to help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160961/164022)
- [What should happen to closed questions?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205/96)
- [Which of these posts should be deleted?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215/96)
- [What's the difference between down-vote, vote to close and flag ?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/199/96)

Answer (score 4):

This question and this answer are my way of trying to encourage more of this sort of thing.

Posters with sufficient reputation could, as well as being nice, be a little **more** vigorous in casting down votes for obviously bad questions; casting close votes for closable questions; and in [the list of closed non-duplicate questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%22possible+Duplicate%3A%22+closed%3A1+), either voting to delete, or editing and voting to re-open, each one as appropriate.

And both the [undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate) and [research-undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-undergraduate) tags are hotbeds of closable, deletable questions: questions about undergraduate study are off-topic here. I have a hunch that the very presence of those tags here is problematic.

There are also plenty of bad questions out there with positive scores.  **Voting down is as important as voting up**, in helping future readers quickly separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: Is there an easy way to skip duplicates? I know I can search "closed:yes" but is there a way to only get non-duplicate closes?

Comment: I am not sure how I feel about down voting questions, especially when you have the ability to close vote. I can't think of too many questions which I wanted to vote down but not close.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - See [this related meta question and answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161787/139256)

Comment: @eykanal nice one - I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @eykanal the search doesn't work any more. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - Quick search on meta brings up [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163628/139256), which I haven't tested; try it out and let me know if it works.